# How to scroll two div simultaneously on Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, mozilla

I have two div in a bootstrap modal.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="textarea_before forScroll" >        
   </div> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="textarea_after forScroll" >        
   </div> 
</div>
```

I gave style like this

```
.textarea_before,.textarea_after{
        height: calc(100vh - 300px);
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding:5px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        overflow: scroll;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        display: flex;
    }
```

And I have written jQuery code like this

```
var subCatContainer = $(".forScroll");
subCatContainer.scroll(function() {
   subCatContainer.scrollTop ($(this).scrollTop ());
});
```

It is working fine in Chrome. But it's not working on Mozilla Firefox. Can anyone help me to find where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe try this: `$(".forScroll").scroll(function() {
   $(".forScroll").not(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});` works for me in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Carsten mention in comment, you need to add `.not(this)` in your jQuery to make sure it is adjusting scroll only to the div that you are not currently scrolling.

DEMO must be check full page:

```js
var subCatContainer = $(".forScroll");
subCatContainer.scroll(function() {
   subCatContainer.not(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop ());
});
```

```css
.textarea_before,.textarea_after{
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="textarea_before forScroll" >   
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
     </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="textarea_after forScroll" >   
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
       Lorem <br>
     </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```